# Parse: Basic App to App Communication

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am trying to figure out what the basic steps are for getting data passed between users.  For example, say I, a user of the app, want to send another user of my app a message or a geopoint or some other form of data.  I know the first step would be posting the data to Parse, which I don't have a problem with.  But then, how would the other user know there is data to retrieve and also how would they go about retrieving it.  Are push notifications the proper and only way of letting the recipient's app know its being sent something? When the recipient app knows there is data posted intended for it to retrieve, how does it go about locating it with a PFQuery? Does the posting app need to supply the receiving app with a UID of some form that the receiving app can then use in its query to locate the data?  This is kind of the last puzzle piece for my app and unfortunately it's the only thing Parse didn't make clear to me.  It is more than likely user error on my part not finding the correct documentation but, app to app communication is key in most apps and so I need to figure out the defacto way that Parse accomplishes this.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a relational table lets say "Messages" table in Parse,

with properties, sender (Pointer to a User), recipient (Pointer to a User) and message (String). and maybe a 'read' Boolean.

You could then query the messages table, With something like:

PSEUDO:

get all messages where recipient is equal to logged in user.

and display these messages on the UI.

Its pretty straightforward, I have done simple messaging service with Parse before

Comment: And you could create a "onSave" hook function (or whatever Parse calls it) to send a push notification to the message's recipient when the sender creates a new message.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! In the end, I think it is best for a device to not have to be querying for changes but rather to be notified when it has new data to retrieve.  Thus, for my uses, I think a combination of your answers, especially with the "onSave" hook function mentioned by Bruno, is the best solution.